# How to capture SignalR native client losing connection with server

Tags: signalr.client

I am working on a .net client application which utilizes SignalR. I want to notify the user if the connection is down for some reason. How can I capture the disconnect event using the native client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client will go into the reconnecting when the connection dies.

Therefore you can tie into the Reconnecting event to see when the connection goes down:

```
var connection = new Connection("http://myEndPointURL");

connection.Reconnecting += () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("The connection has gone down, shifting into reconnecting state");
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It looks like this is only supported for PersistentConnections. Can I do something similar with Hubs?

Comment: The hubs also have a reconnecting event =)

Comment: Actually, I don't see Reconnecting as an event I can capture, just Reconnected.

Comment: OK - looking at the source code for SignalR I see both the Reconnected and Reconnecting events, but I have pulled the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR nuget package into my project, and it errors on Reconnecting. It only shows Reconnecting. Should I be using a different package?

Comment: ` Error 2 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubConnection' does not 
 contain a definition for 'Reconnecting' and no extension method 
 'Reconnecting' accepting a first argument of type 
 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubConnection' could be found 
 (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `

Comment: I updated to the RC version released yesterday and now have Reconnecting available.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to capture StateChanged to detect changes in the connection and notify the user.

```
        connection.StateChanged += (statechange) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Changing from " + statechange.OldState + " to " + statechange.NewState);
            };
```

This gives me a mechanism to notify the user when the connection is dropped or successfully reconnected.